# How to set static IP details for WiFi using Apple Configurator?

Tags: wifi, apple-configurator

I am using Apple Configurator 1.7.1 (550) on 10.10.2 (Yosemite).

Is it possible to prepare a device and assign the static IP address for a WiFi?

I am able to successfully prepare and supervise the iPad, but since we use static IP addresses for each device, I am having enter these details in manually every time I have maintain and add some update to the device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Configuration profiles do not allow you to apply a static IP address to a device.
Instead, it would be highly recommended to configure static IP addressing within the DHCP server itself. This would accomplish what you want without worrying about which profile goes on what device, etc. Configurator can also export the MAC addresses to make life easier in setting this up.
Right click the 'All Devices' in the Supervise tab, click Export Info > Device Information > WiFi MAC Address.

Comment: Enterprise WiFi is severely limited and DHCP is not provided. We have asked, but since we are the first in our organization to even be allowed a private WiFi across the campus, the network team is very conservative in their approach.

Comment: So you need a script to take over your manual work ?

Comment: Maybe... How does a script work to set the ip on the iPad? Each device will have its own static ip. The unique identifier is the serial number or wifi Mac for each iPad.

Comment: That is a very nice way of saying the are just lazy, you call it conservative :) as for the script right now I do not know, but lets do some research.